# "Come at" and "come over at"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, informal-language

Are "come at" and "come over at" slang, idioms, dialectual, informal or bad English?

- If you ever visit London, come at my place.
- If you happen to be in town, come over at my shop.

Comment: Neither are idiomatic. It's optional whether to include ***over***, but the standard form is *come [over] **to** my place* (or ***round***, but you wouldn't usually include ***over*** with that preposition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your uses are acceptable in the sentences you've written. In both, you need to use "to". I don't even think they're slang or regional.

> - If you ever visit London, come to my place.
> - If you ever happen to be in town, come over to my shop.

Now, there's *generally* nothing wrong with either "come over at" or "come at"... but you only have specific times they work... for example, if you are telling someone **when** to arrive:

> The party is at 3 pm but if you want to help me get ready, *come over at* noon.
>   I'm telling everyone to *come at* 6 pm for dinner.

These are perfectly acceptable everyday usage.

---

One notable (?) example of a regular but slightly odd usage is the idiomatic phrase/meme made popular on the US TV show *Jersey Shore*.

> [Come at me, bro.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/come-at-me-bro)

Comment: I guess it's because **at** is a preposition of place and time and answers to **where** and **when** and not **where to**.